# What does the SMTP status 250 BONHAM COOLED BY FIRE mean?

Tags: smtp, logging

I noticed this in my email server logs recently:

> status=sent (250 OK BONHAM COOLED BY FIRE ...)

I searched, and the only reference I could find anywhere else on the internet was [in this anonymous bpaste:](http://bpaste.net/show/7a4ACBV8iDqyKZw1zLbs/)

> Aug 23 03:57:56 emailer1 postfix/smtp[2028]: 64B5774FA4: to=, relay=mxi3p.craigslist.org[208.82.236.82]:25, delay=12, delays=1.1/0.01/9.5/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK BONHAM COOLED BY FIRE (95194B88-D96B-4473-89DB-7222F04B088B.1))

My log entry is also from the Craigslist remailer. Is this just a funny, jokey custom status code that only Craigslist uses?

Does anyone know what it means? Is it a reference to John Bonham of Led Zeppelin?

Comment: The number (250) is the more important part.  The rest is text supplied by the mail server.  For a 250 code, the text is typically "Requested mail action okay completed" or something like that.  I assume this is just the guy who compiled the MTA at CL having some fun.

Comment: Actually the satus code is 250. They just append more text ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

250 means that the message was accepted for delivery. The human-readable portion of it can say anything, and it appears that this is someone's attempt at humor.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what what "BONHAM" or "FIRE" refer to?

Comment: No idea. Better ask the mail server administrator.

Comment: "BONHAM COOLED BY FIRE" is the CL ops team's version of "Darmok and Jalad at Tanagra" http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Darmok_(episode)

Comment: Sokath, his eyes uncovered!

Answer (score 2):

The long string in brackets is the UUID as generated by [Haraka](http://haraka.github.io), the SMTP server that Craigslist uses. This helps them track any issues down to the exact log lines. The text after 250, as everyone else rightly pointed out, is custom. In Haraka you can create a "queue_ok" hook to customize this message, the default of which is simply "Message Queued ()".

I'll ask the guy who developed their mail infrastructure what the meaning is. Or maybe he will reply here.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'd certainly be interested in hearing about this inscrutable phrase from the horse's mouth.